# How to create a list of possible combinations of strings in a cell separated by a comma

Tags: vba, excel, combinations

So let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have a list of events with two columns: Event ID and Guests. In the Guests field I have the email of every participant of that specific event separated by a comma. Each event has a different number of participants. What I need is to list all possible combinations of guests for each event. It looks something like this:

Assume in one meeting the participants are A, B, C, D

This represents the following unique 1:1 connections

```
AB
AC
AD
BC
BD
CD
```

Do any of you know a code that could get to this output?

@Gary's Student Thanks!

This is what I have, but it's not working properly.

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHiz3.png)

```
 Sub test1()


Set l1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AZ10000").Find("Event ID", lookat:=xlPart) 'Location of event id field
Set l2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AZ10000").Find("Participants123", lookat:=xlPart) 'Location of guests field
Last = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim c As Double
Dim l As Double
l = l2.Row + 1



For i = 1 To Last

    last1 = Sheet1.Cells(l, l2.Column).End(xlToRight).Column
    c = Application.Combin(last1 - 3, 2)
    Rows(l + 1 & ":" & l + c - 1).Insert
'Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
    N = last1
    K = l
    For b = 4 To N - 1
        For j = b + 1 To N
            Cells(K, 2).Value = Cells(l, b).Value
            Cells(K, 3).Value = Cells(l, j).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next b
    l = l + c



Next i

End Sub
```

! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxZny.jpg)

Comment: Do you have problem with algorithm or code? If with the first one - this is not proper place to ask, if the second - show us what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Place the names in column **A** and run something like this:

```
Sub dural()
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, K As Long
    N = 4
    K = 1
    For i = 1 To N - 1
        For j = i + 1 To N
            Cells(K, 2).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value & Cells(j, 1).Value
            K = K + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

This assumes that you only need pairs so *ABC* is not considered.  Also assumes that *AB* and *BA* are the same.

Comment: Than you Gary! I tried to adapt the code but for not reason is not working. You can see what I have in the post above. Please let me know if you have any thoughts on why the code is not working!